# Trickling noise from thermal store

Tags: central-heating, noise

First off, I'm in the UK. I've provided links to some terms I've used in case they're not universal.

I recently installed a used thermal store. It's set up as a [vented](https://www.theheatinghub.co.uk/open-vented-sealed-central-heating-systems) [S-plan](https://www.plumberparts.co.uk/advice/heating-systems/s-plan-heating-system) system. When the valve feeding the cylinder is open AND the pump is on, there is a constant trickling noise.

There is a manual air vent just above the valve, as close to the cylinder union as it possibly could be. You can see this to the left of the wiring centre in the picture. The vent pipe itself exits at the top of the cylinder, so I would expect any collecting air to discharge through that in any case.   And there's a [TPRV](https://www.toolstation.com/strom-12-temperature-pressure-relief-valve/p87709?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=googleshoppingfeed&gclid=CjwKCAiAi4fwBRBxEiwAEO8_Hvdhe18ty2uBnbUwOl4L6Mqp_HpFm8mG9MgHvOF0ZGJnWEcCJ_p4yBoCwccQAvD_BwE) (to the right of the wiring centre) that I can also use to vent any air.

I really don't understand how there can be any air in the cylinder to produce noise, given all of this. I'm at a loss for how to get rid of the noise.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Very interesting and well-documented question; let's hope one of our pros can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I read Harry Potter but I really don't understand how magic is done in the UK or how prevalent it is. Because plain Muggle TPRV doesn't remove air automatically... you have to actuate them manually. Not something I'd do lightly.

Comment: As I said "Can use to vent any air", not that it did it automatically. The manual itself offers this as a (recommended) venting possibility. The vent above the valve is also manual, rather than an automatic bleed valve.